# Relation between permutations and fourier transform?

Tags: combinatorics, fourier-series, permutations

i dont know if this is already addressed somewhere (searching around did not find sth).

The motivation is to find a way to generate or produce permutations using concepts from continuous mathematics (instead of discrete).

How can one generate permutations of the $n$ items using for example rotations?

This reminds how clocks work. A clock has a number of gearwheels inter-connected with various (multiples of same number) sizes (or radii).

[image]

A small gearwheel will rotate by a step (the basic step or *frequency*).

Once the smaller gearwheel fulfils a full rotation (by a sequence of steps), the immediately larger gearwheel turns by one step and the process starts again from the smaller wheels, and so on until the largest wheel has completed a full rotation (and all? premutations are produced).

One can easily see that this mechanism in fact generates permutations of $n$ items (with no duplicates?)

This is related to how [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutations) are factored into [cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutations#Cycle_notation) and also how the [Fisher-Yates-Knuth Shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) works.

This can be modeled by complex numbers $e^{ik2\pi/n}$ (or equivalently as modulo arithmetic), $n$ is number of items and $k$ represents the $k$'th element (or maybe $k$'th element's gearwheel size).

This is reminiscent of [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

> Is the [(discrete) Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) related to generation of permutations? If so
>   how?
>
> **Extra note** What would be a randomized version of the previous process?

PS. As an aside this example provides an intuitive understanding of the $+ k2\pi$ periodicity. Like this: at a specific time a small wheel may have made several full rotations (while a larger wheel not a full rotation), in this sense, although the smaller wheel would be in a same position the $+ k2\pi$ periodicity **could** carry information about the larger(s) wheel(s) current rotation (extracted by appropriate factoring).

Comment: When you say the gear rotations produce all permutations, what do you mean by "permutations"? Permutations of what? As I understand it, you're *cycling*, not permuting.

Comment: @blue, hmm yes , lets say each gear on a gear wheel is numbered from $1$ to $n$, and lets assume an orientation of the wheels (much like the picture shown) where the *measurement* of a wheel happens only at the vertical top. Then each configuration of the wheels (eg. wheel 1 $\implies k_1$, wheel2 $\implies k_2$, etc..) meaning $item_1$ goes to position $k_1$, $item_2$ to pos. $k_2$ etc.., represents an ordering (or permutation) of the $n$ elements of a set

Comment: What if each wheel has $1$ at the top? $1,1,1,\cdots$ is not a permutation of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$. If you stipulate that the top gear of each wheel is distinct, then sure, the top gears in sequence are a permutation of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ ... but then what in the world are the rest of the gears and the wheels for?

Comment: @blue then this *represents* the *identical* permutation (each item stays in the same position it is in). It might be easier t think of the numbers on each gear as displacements instead of absolute positions

Comment: @blue, interesting, by symmetry assuming another orientation should produce isomporphic permutations (e.g measuring the extreme right position of each wheel instead of extreme top), etc.. this is just a model to relate to fourier transforms

Comment: Maybe someone else will come along and figure out what you're talking about and enlighten me. Good luck in the meantime.

Comment: I don’t think the gears bring anything new here , all your description is saying is that the two gears rolling onto each other with numbered teeth are equivalent to a map from one gear to another. Anyway , for the Fourier transform you may be interested in reading about the subject additive combinatorics .